# Branching in Codeplex hosted TFS

Tags: tfs, codeplex

I'm setting up a Codeplex project for the first time using TFS. A team project was created for me with the name of the project, "switchboard". So my original thought was to create a main and a branches folders under that like this:

```
$/switchboard/main
$/switchboard/branches
$/switchboard/branches/v1.0
$/switchboard/branches/v1.2
etc.
```

However, looking around at other projects, on the Source Code tab, they have a drop down list that has their main, v1.0, v1.2 and so on as items. I would prefer doing this mainly because it is cleaner to navigate starting from the top of one branch. Also because when someone chooses download then will only get the selected branch instead of all branches.

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to get the drop down list in my project or how it fits in with the TFS structure/navigation. Are the items on the drop down list additional Team Projects within the one Codeplex project? Or is there a way to promote the top level folders under the one Team Project such that they are on the drop down list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like your folder structure - that will help you in your future work. The drop-down listbox you can see on some projects are shown on projects that are using the [Mercurial source control system](http://mercurial.selenic.com/). Here is an example:

[image: WiX project]

You can get more information here:

https://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Source%20Control

and

https://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20TortoiseHG%20with%20CodePlex

Comment: Perfect, thanks Morten. That was another possibility I had in the back of my mind - that maybe it was characteristic of a different type of source control.